# Where can I ask "where can I find a piece of code which does X?"-style questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Very often, instead of asking "How can go about doing X (in code)?", which is typically a legitimate SO question, I assume others have done this before me, and start typing in the question "Where can I find a piece of code / library / app which does X?" ... but then I remember that I'm not supposed to ask those kind of questions (because they fall under "Product or service recommendations or comparisons")

So, where do I ask these kinds of questions? Or am I misinterpreting the guidelines?

Comment: SoftwareRecs? Or just Google for them! Also *"How can I go about doing..."* seems much too broad for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I was generalizing here, obviously actual questions would be a lot more specific than that...

Comment: Maybe you could link to some examples of questions that you think this would apply to?

Comment: @TinyGiant: Not a link, but how about "How do I instrument my C++ application with file-based configuration?", which becomes "which libraries for C++ app configuration are out there, and what are their respective pros and cons".

Comment: @einpoklum that to me is an odd question, since that would imply that app configuration is something standardized and thus can be molded into a library. But it is not, it is by definition application specific. Basic file access is all you need. Of course you might apply some standard data formatting which can easily be read back, such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Search engines are designed for this purpose.

Comment: @Gimby: I assume you've never used .NET's built-in app configuration library, then. Such a thing certainly can and does exist and can and does go well beyond merely abstracting XML data access.

Comment: Nine time out of ten the code/formula/algorithm questions that fall into this category can be answered by typing the question's title into the SO search engine.

Answer (score 21):

Oh, wow, didn't notice that...

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Perhaps this should be made more visible to SO visitors.

Comment: Well, there's a lot of "subexchanges" under the stackexchange domain, we can't really make all of them more visible :)

Comment: Plus, they have standards as well, we don't just want to just toss junk their way.

Comment: Be aware of their **VERY** strict [quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). If you find SO tough, you've found your match...

Comment: Well, it *is* in the list within the Stack Exchange dropdown. I would assume it's left out of the footer due to being Beta. Or, are you suggesting it be added as an option in the closing dialog?

Comment: @ivarni: Well, this point causes innumerable SO questions to be reject as out-of-scope. People don't really ask questions about Game of Thrones or Jewish religious customs here.

Comment: @TiesonT.: I think it should appear in the FAQ/Tour next to the declaration that requests for recommendations are off-topic, and that when a question is closed for this reason, A link there should be added to the notice. Finally, I think it might be appropriate to migrate questions there.

Comment: As @rene already pointed out, softwarerecs has very strict rules about what kind of posts they want. I have a sneaking suspicion that a lot of what gets closed here would be closed there as well. Linking it in the close-reason could cause a lot of friction. And if SO does it, should they also add links to programmers, codereview, serverfault, superuser, webmasters, etc? It really falls on the asker to figure out where their question belongs, not us.

Comment: @ivarni: Well, I might not be the ultimate specimen, but I'm a SO yser with over 4,500 rep, with accounts on several other sites (some with > 1,000 rep) and yet I never head about softwarerecs before. Which is why I believe it is probably not visible enough. As for their strictness - maybe you're right, I don't know. Hopefully people can adapt their questions to softwarerecs' standards.

Answer (score 1):

For medium-sized pieces of code - larger than a few lines, but smaller than a self-contained library - I don't think Stack Exchange provides a solution. I think that is correct. It is too much like bespoke work, and not a good fit to the Q&A format.

However, I have found the following resources useful when looking for my own code samples:

- Open-source project code in [Github](https://github.com/)
- [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) is a site dedicated to providing code samples in multiple languages.
- For well-known algorithms, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) quite often includes implementations in a common language or pseudo-code.

You can also ask on more open-ended discussion forums, and the worst that is likely to happen there is no answer (whilst in Stack Exchange you will likely get the question closed and may get down-voted for your trouble).